# Can type theory be viewed as an alternative to model theory?

Tags: logic, model-theory, type-theory

While type theory certainly has traditionally been used for different purposes than model theory, as noted in this [Philosophy SE post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7122/is-model-theory-for-logic-a-kind-of-type-theory), I wonder to what extent type theory could model *model theory itself*.

My motivation for this question is based on an observation that we can view the typing relation in type theory as analagous to the "is a model of" relation in model theory. For example, one might regard the Sigma type $Magma(A) :\equiv\Sigma_{a:A} A \rightarrow A \rightarrow A$ as the theory of magmas over a type A, and components of said type models of the theory.

Now certainly, model theory has more structure to it than a simple "*x is a model of y*" relation between theories and models of those theories, but I think the idea of interpreting types and terms as a theory/model relation begs the question: Can we develop a richer language in type theory to deal with this types as theories, terms as models interpretation in order to interpret traditional (i.e. ZFC-based) model theory within a type theoretic framework? And, if full interpretation with classical model theory is not possible, is there still some meaningful *type-based model theory* that we could develop?

Comment: The theory of magmas is not really interesting, since it has no axioms! Can you describe how you would handle theories _with_ axioms? (Even so, I'm not sure I understand your example. Isn't $\Pi_{a:A}A$ normally just a way to write $A\to A$? Why are you using both that and $\to$ in your expression?)

Comment: Not quite. Pi types are more general than function types. But I believe I actually should have used a sigma type in this instance, so I will edit my post. You can basically read $\Pi$ as $\forall$, and $\Sigma$ as $\exists$.

One could express the theory of semigroups as: $Semigroup(A) :\equiv \Sigma_{m:A \rightarrow A \rightarrow A}\Pi_{a,b,c:A}Id(m(a,m(b,c)),(m(m(a,b),c))$ Where $Id$ is the identity type of proofs that two terms are equal, for a more interesting example. Similarly, you could describe the theory of groups, or rings.

Comment: x @Sintrastes: My understanding (but it's a long time since I worked with dependent types) is that $\Pi$ reduces to a function arrow when the bound variable isn't free in the body, as in $\Pi_{a:A} A$ -- and similarly $\Sigma_{a:A}A$ would be the same as $A\times A$.

Comment: I think you are asking whether, rather than studying model theory using set theory, you could study model theory using type theory as your metatheory. Sure, you could do that.

Comment: @Carl Mummert Could you elaborate? I assume the question is implicitly, "would you get some interesting insight or a different view of model theory in doing so?".

Comment: @CarlMummert I think I could more pointedly ask whether we could either study model theory with type theory as the metatheory or study models *in* a type theory. I think in the latter case, this would be a relatively simple thing to do, as there are those who already study *categorical model theory* -- viewing models as functors into certain categories (usually $\mathbf{Set}$, but conceivably the category associated with a type theory as well). However, I'd still like to know if anyone is or has studied this specifically.

Answer (score 3):

Denoting $\mathcal{U}$ as a type universe, one usualy one writes $\mathsf{MagmaStr} : \mathcal{U} \to \mathcal{U}$ for the magma structure over some type. As allready noted the magma structure of $A$ is just a map $A \times A \to A$ so it should be $\mathsf{MagmaStr}(A) = A \times A \to A$.

For a type theoretical definition of $\mathsf{Magma} : \mathcal{U_1}$ itself I would write $\mathsf{Magma} = \sum_{A : \mathcal{U}} A \times A \to A$ note that this type, the magmas in a the universe $\mathcal{U}$, lives in a higher universe level. Then a member of $\mathsf{Magma}$ is a pair of of a type $A$ and a binary operator on $A$ living in $\mathcal{U}$. In that way the type $\mathsf{Magma}$ can be seen as a theory and the members of this type as its models.

Ofcourse the $\mathsf{Magma}$ answer is somewhat simplistic but the above readily generalizes to for example a $\mathsf{SemiGroup} = \sum_{G : \mathcal{U}} \sum_{* : G \times G \to G} \prod_{a b c : M} (a * b) * c = a * (b * c)$. Which is a bit more involved as you can see.

It think that within this framework a lot model theory can be done, at least if the type theory is rich enough.

Comment: Thank you. I think I can add to this now, that while I have yet to see any literature on type theory being used as an explicit alternative to model theory, the field of categorical semantics is essentially a categorical alternative to classical (set theoretic) model theory -- and category theory and type theory are of course closely related.